Kubernetes POD sends RST packet intermittantly
I have a test application which is java Springboot web app. It has a GET API which has latency of 1 second.
I invoke this REST api the rate of 50 calls/minute and it works okay, no errors on ingress or logs. Then I introduce the delay via code, that is, have the Thread wait 30 seconds before responding back, and this too works flawless with 50calls/minute.
Now I revert the GET API back to 1 second latency and retest by introducing 30s delay via chaos test tool. This is causing some of the requests to fall out with 502 bad gateway error at the Client.
On the ingress I see below errors:
[error] 1391018#1391018: *107956973 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, 
client: 151.XX.XXX.6, server: abcd.corp.intranet, request: "GET /getHello/0 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.XX.XX.137:9023/getHello/0", host: "abcd.corp.intranet"

I tried setting timeouts on the ingress as below but it did not help.
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '600'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout: '600'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '600'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '600'

On the server side below are the timeouts configured:
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=60000
server.tomcat.accept-count=100
server.tomcat.keep-alive-timeout=60000
server.tomcat.max-keep-alive-requests=200
server.tomcat.max-connections=400
server.tomcat.threads.max=200
server.tomcat.threads.min-spare=20

Then I went to the underlying pods (2 pods) and took a TCPDUMP and found that the Server is sending RST package right away for few of the requests.
TCPMDUMP result:

I am unsure what is causing the server to send RST. Much appreciated if anyone can point me in the right direction. What else could I look into to find out what is going on to arrive at the solution.

One cause of connection reset in K8s clusters which I have seen a few times has to do with the conntrack table being full. You may want to review that as well.
Also take a look at the article: Debugging an Intermittent Connection Reset. Perhaps it could guide you to a resolution.
